# How to find the number of adjacent pairs in an array that have a difference greater than "n"?

Tags: python, arrays

I am wondering how I would find the number of adjacent pairs in an array that have a difference greater than n in python

For instance, let's take array a,

```
a=[1, 3, 6, 7, 15]
```

if `n=2`
then the answer would be `2`

This is because `6-3 > 2` and `15-7 > 3`

Comment: Are you able to generate the adjacent pairs of the list (we don't call them arrays in Python; that means something else)? Are you able to check the difference of those pairs? Are you able to count up the results? What exactly don't you know how to do here?

Comment: Does the list have to be monotonically increasing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
count = 0
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    if abs(a[i] - a[i-1]) > n:
        count+=1

print(count)
```

Comment: Your code works only for sorted (in increasing order) data. Consider the input `[10, 7, 4, 1]` though…

Answer (score 4):

You could use `zip` in a list comprehension, and subtract consecutive pairs to see what the differences are:

```
sum(abs(i-j)>2 for i,j in zip(a[1:], a[:-1]))
```

---

A few comments on the above:

`zip` aggregates elements from multiple iterables into tuples. You can use it to generate tuples of *adjacent* pairs:

```
list(zip(a[1:], a[:-1]))
# [(3, 1), (6, 3), (7, 6), (15, 7)]
```

`abs(i-j)>2` returns a boolean indicating whether the conditions is satisfied or not. `sum` will then add up all booleans:

```
[abs(i-j)>2 for i,j in zip(a[1:], a[:-1])]
# [False, True, False, True]
```